# Why can I not pull this field? Php / Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Why can't i pull this field `pID` from the the database?

I have the following php:

```
<?php
// Get course information cID, prefix, code and dept info : name
$cID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'cID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if(!$cID) {
    echo "No cID specified.";
    exit;
}
require_once('inc/dbc1.php');
$pdo4 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###', $username, $password);
$pdo4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('
    SELECT fname, lname
    FROM Course Cou, Comment Comm, Professor P
    WHERE Cou.cID = ?
    AND P.pID = Comm.pID
    GROUP BY concat(fname, lname);
    ');
$sth4->execute(array(
    $cID
));
?>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<a href='prof.php?pID={$row['pID']}' title='Drexel Professor Comments for {$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}'>
```

[image: img]

The above is pulling the fname and lname fields, but the first call for pID is not being pulled.

- If I add pID to the select statement,
  it gives me the ambiguous pID error

  .

Anyone??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the field to the select statement, otherwise it won't be part of the result set.

> If I add pID to the select statement, it gives me the ambiguous pID error

Then make it unambiguous:

```
 SELECT fname, lname, P.pID
```

should work.

Comment: That works, so ambigious just basically means - I have no clue from which column you want me to pull out of?? Haha

Comment: @user "ambiguous" means that there is more than one table in your `FROM` part that contains the column name `pID`.  It needs you to add the name of the table you want to pull it from.

Comment: @user700070 - that's exactly what ambiguous means: the unqualified identifier matches more than one column in the joined table and mysql has no idea which one you meant. Why is that "Haha"?

Answer (score 0):

Add `P.pID` to your select statement since it is defined in two tables:

```
select P.pID
[...]
```